# SQL - Should I store targets in history or join on the way into BI tool? What is more efficient?

Tags: sql

Edit - TL;DR should static, redundant metadata be stored in history or joined to history at time of data pull for full data refreshes?

For example, say I have a table with historical sales information by month and year which is aggregated at the product, state, region level.

Now assume I have product-specific "targets" that I want to apply to all current and historical sales.  The targets are the same for all months, years, states and regions.

Is there a general best practice regarding whether to (a) join to the targets table and store the targets with the history each time data is refreshed or (b) join the entire history to the targets table on the way into the BI tool each time data is refreshed?

If targets are stored in history, then a one shot of history will be required to change targets.

I would appreciate any thoughts or discussion at all as this is a scenario I run into frequently.

In the past, I used a third option which involved joining a number of dimensional tables at the very end of the process which was clearly inefficient so I removed that in the current process but now I find myself one-shotting history with any changes.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.Is your goal to see the amount/percentage of a target fulfilled? what exactly are you trying to do with these joins? 2. If the targets are same for month/year/state/region, is it only affected by product? In this case, it could just by a field in the product table, and you could make a view that return what I meantion in (1), IF that is what you want

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Good question.  The BI tool displays the actuals vs target.  I am simply passing the targets to the BI tool.  So the join is simply to add the applicable target to each row in the history table during each individual refresh OR to add applicable target to each row for the entire history table every time data is passed to the BI tool.  I should clarify that the table sent to the BI tool for each refresh is cumulative, i.e. the BI tool does a complete refresh of the data each time it is refresh and NOT an incremental refresh.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Regarding #2, I agree that targets can be in product table but should I include targets in history or just join targets before full refresh of BI tool?

Comment: In other words should it be join targets ==> store in history table ==> BI "_in" table or store all BUT targets in history table ==> join targets ==> BI "_in" table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are thinking of when mentioning "best practice".

Keeping a targets value in history is more performant, since you only need to update the value on cells that have none. Joining each time takes resources.

However, there is an important business thing involved which you should consider and probably takes this question out of this site. Can transactions by inserted delayed? If yes, this means that the join-method, being "dynamic", will consider the new transaction, whereas the save-target-to-history method won't! Targets, many times, affect employee bonuses...an important thing. You have to be careful and check your company's/client's specification in order to be sure about this. AFTER this, if you still have choices, you may consider the design from a performance aspect.

Comment: This almost exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I'm definitely interested in performance so storing in history sounds like the right approach ; especially provided that, with proper backup and testing, one shotting target updates to entire history is acceptable.